# rails controller to ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a right good query here. Believe this is what i need to do.

I've got this line of code.

```
event = client.get_listings_by_event 1296393
```

Now, This code is in a private def method. Lets call it data.

In my show method i have it listed as data.

I'm wanting to have the response from this (that i'm currently able to use in byebug) and use it in my javascript file i have running and already sorting other apis.

This is the byebug response i get

```
#<GogoKit::Listing:0x007faa0b888058 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"links"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>links @options={:as=>"_links", :instance=>#<Proc:0x007faa0284d150@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/roar-1.0.4/lib/roar/json/hal.rb:191 (lambda)>, :exec_context=>:decorator, :getter=>#<Proc:0x007faa0284c890@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/roar-1.0.4/lib/roar/hypermedia.rb:139 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :extend=>Roar::JSON::HAL::Links::LinkCollectionRepresenter}>, "id"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>id @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"id"}>, "number_of_tickets"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>number_of_tickets @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"number_of_tickets"}>, "seating"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>seating @options={:class=>GogoKit::Seating, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070eeda0@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:37 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"seating", :extend=>GogoKit::SeatingRepresenter}>, "pickup_available"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>pickup_available @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"pickup_available"}>, "download_available"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>download_available @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"download_available"}>, "ticket_price"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>ticket_price @options={:class=>GogoKit::Money, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070ed798@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:43 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"ticket_price", :extend=>GogoKit::MoneyRepresenter}>, "estimated_ticket_price"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>estimated_ticket_price @options={:class=>GogoKit::Money, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070eceb0@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:47 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"estimated_ticket_price", :extend=>GogoKit::MoneyRepresenter}>, "estimated_total_ticket_price"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>estimated_total_ticket_price @options={:class=>GogoKit::Money, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070ec5c8@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:51 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"estimated_total_ticket_price", :extend=>GogoKit::MoneyRepresenter}>, "estimated_booking_fee"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>estimated_booking_fee @options={:class=>GogoKit::Money, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070e7d48@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:55 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"estimated_booking_fee", :extend=>GogoKit::MoneyRepresenter}>, "estimated_shipping"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>estimated_shipping @options={:class=>GogoKit::Money, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070e74b0@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:59 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"estimated_shipping", :extend=>GogoKit::MoneyRepresenter}>, "estimated_vat"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>estimated_vat @options={:class=>GogoKit::Money, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070e6a10@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:63 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"estimated_vat", :extend=>GogoKit::MoneyRepresenter}>, "estimated_total_charge"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>estimated_total_charge @options={:class=>GogoKit::Money, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070e5f48@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:67 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"estimated_total_charge", :extend=>GogoKit::MoneyRepresenter}>, "ticket_type"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>ticket_type @options={:class=>GogoKit::TicketType, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070e5638@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:71 (lambda)>, :embedded=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"ticket_type", :extend=>GogoKit::TicketTypeRepresenter}>, "listing_notes"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>listing_notes @options={:class=>GogoKit::ListingNote, :skip_parse=>#<Proc:0x007faa070e4c60@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource/listing.rb:76 (lambda)>, :embedded=>true, :collection=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"listing_notes", :extend=>GogoKit::ListingNoteRepresenter}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil, :links=>[[{:rel=>:self}, #<Proc:0x007faa0284da38@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource.rb:16>]]}, @links={"self"=>#<Roar::Hypermedia::Hyperlink:0x007faa0b881140 @attrs={"href"=>"https://api.viagogo.net/v2/listings/28107921", "title"=>nil, "templated"=>false, "rel"=>"self"}, @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"_self"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>_self @options={:hash=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"_self"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}>, "listing:deliverymethods"=>#<Roar::Hypermedia::Hyperlink:0x007faa0b87be70 @attrs={"href"=>"https://api.viagogo.net/v2/listings/28107921/deliverymethods", "title"=>nil, "templated"=>false, "rel"=>"listing:deliverymethods"}, @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"_self"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>_self @options={:hash=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"_self"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}>, "listing:event"=>#<Roar::Hypermedia::Hyperlink:0x007faa0b87aae8 @attrs={"href"=>"https://api.viagogo.net/v2/events/1382274", "title"=>nil, "templated"=>false, "rel"=>"listing:event"}, @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"_self"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>_self @options={:hash=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"_self"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}>, "listing:localwebpage"=>#<Roar::Hypermedia::Hyperlink:0x007faa0b879918 @attrs={"href"=>"https://www.viagogo.com/secure/buy/selectquantity?listingId=28107921&eventId=1382274&quantity=1", "title"=>"Buy", "templated"=>false, "rel"=>"listing:localwebpage"}, @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"_self"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>_self @options={:hash=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"_self"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}>, "listing:purchasepreview"=>#<Roar::Hypermedia::Hyperlink:0x007faa0b878400 @attrs={"href"=>"https://api.viagogo.net/v2/listings/28107921/purchasepreview", "title"=>"Buy", "templated"=>false, "rel"=>"listing:purchasepreview"}, @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"_self"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>_self @options={:hash=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"_self"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}>, "listing:webpage"=>#<Roar::Hypermedia::Hyperlink:0x007faa0b872de8 @attrs={"href"=>"https://www.viagogo.com/ww/secure/buy/selectquantity?listingId=28107921&eventId=1382274&quantity=1", "title"=>"Buy", "templated"=>false, "rel"=>"listing:webpage"}, @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"_self"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>_self @options={:hash=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"_self"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}>},
 @id=28107921, @number_of_tickets=1, @seating=#<GogoKit::Seating section="BNCH T", row="31", seat_from=nil, seat_to=nil>, @pickup_available=false, @download_available=false, @ticket_price=#<GogoKit::Money:0x007faa0b868348 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"amount"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>amount @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"amount"}>, "currency_code"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>currency_code @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"currency_code"}>, "display"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>display @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"display"}>},
  :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}, @amount=49.73, @currency_code="USD", @display="$49.73">, @estimated_ticket_price=#<GogoKit::Money:0x007faa0b8621c8 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"amount"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>amount @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"amount"}>, "currency_code"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>currency_code @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"currency_code"}>, "display"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>display @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"display"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}, @amount=49.73, @currency_code="USD", @display="$49.73">, @estimated_total_ticket_price=#<GogoKit::Money:0x007faa0b8600a8 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"amount"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>amount @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"amount"}>, "currency_code"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>currency_code @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"currency_code"}>, "display"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>display @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"display"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}, @amount=49.73, @currency_code="USD", @display="$49.73">, @estimated_booking_fee=#<GogoKit::Money:0x007faa035f98f8 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"amount"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>amount @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"amount"}>, "currency_code"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>currency_code @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"currency_code"}>, "display"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>display @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"display"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}, @amount=7.46, @currency_code="USD", @display="$7.46">, @estimated_shipping=#<GogoKit::Money:0x007faa035f3430 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"amount"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>amount @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"amount"}>, "currency_code"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>currency_code @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"currency_code"}>, "display"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>display @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"display"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}, @amount=0.0, @currency_code="USD", @display="$0.00">, @estimated_vat=#<GogoKit::Money:0x007faa035f0c58 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"amount"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>amount @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"amount"}>, "currency_code"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>currency_code @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"currency_code"}>, "display"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>display @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"display"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}, @amount=1.49, @currency_code="USD", @display="$1.49">, @estimated_total_charge=#<GogoKit::Money:0x007faa035e9f20 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"amount"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>amount @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"amount"}>, "currency_code"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>currency_code @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"currency_code"}>, "display"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>display @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"display"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}, @amount=58.68, @currency_code="USD", @display="$58.68">, @ticket_type=#<GogoKit::TicketType:0x007faa0b85be40 @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"links"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>links @options={:as=>"_links", :instance=>#<Proc:0x007faa0284d150@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/roar-1.0.4/lib/roar/json/hal.rb:191 (lambda)>, :exec_context=>:decorator, :getter=>#<Proc:0x007faa0284c890@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/roar-1.0.4/lib/roar/hypermedia.rb:139 (lambda)>, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :extend=>Roar::JSON::HAL::Links::LinkCollectionRepresenter}>, "type"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>type @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"type"}>, "name"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>name @options={:parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"name"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil, :links=>[[{:rel=>:self}, #<Proc:0x007faa0284da38@/Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gogokit-0.4.1/lib/gogokit/resource.rb:16>]]}, @links={"self"=>#<Roar::Hypermedia::Hyperlink:0x007faa0b859f28 @attrs={"href"=>"https://api.viagogo.net/v2/tickettypes/ETicketThirdPartyPreUpload", "title"=>nil, "templated"=>false, "rel"=>"self"}, @representable_attrs={:features=>{Representable::JSON=>true}, :definitions=>{"_self"=>#<Representable::Definition ==>_self @options={:hash=>true, :parse_filter=>[], :render_filter=>[], :as=>"_self"}>}, :options=>{}, :wrap=>nil}>}, @type="ETicketThirdPartyPreUpload", @name="E-Ticket">, @listing_notes=[]>
```

Obviously this only the first item, How would i go about passing this through to the javascript ajax?

Would the ajax request even be able to handle this format?

This is my current ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://',
    success: function(json) {
```

Would i just put in the url area data.event?

Here is all my code:

```
def gogodata
    # All methods require OAuth2 authentication. To get OAuth2 credentials for your
    # application, see http://developer.viagogo.net/#authentication.
    client = GogoKit::Client.new do |config|
      config.client_id = ENV['viagogo_key']
      config.client_secret = ENV['viagogo_secret']
    end



    # Get an access token. See http://developer.viagogo.net/#getting-access-tokens
    token = client.get_client_access_token
    client.access_token = token.access_token


    # Get a list of events, categories, venues and metro areas that match the given
    # search query

    event = client.get_listings_by_event @event.viagogolink
    byebug
    # Get the different event genres (see http://developer.viagogo.net/#entities)
    genres = client.get_genres



  end
```

**Edit**

i get this error,
ActionController::UnknownFormat

on this 
 respond_with event
 If it helps heres the code

```
  respond_to :json, only: :data

   def data
     client = GogoKit::Client.new do |config|
       config.client_id = ENV['viagogo_key']
       config.client_secret = ENV['viagogo_secret']
     end
     token = client.get_client_access_token
     client.access_token = token.access_token
     event = client.get_listings_by_event(params[:id])
      respond_with event
   end
```

[image: imageoferror]

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use the data in the front-end (publicly), you'd need to first make the `event` data "public" (by your own admission, your current implementation is *private*), and then make sure your app can access it via the routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :clients do
   scope constraints: { format: "json" } do
      get :data, on: :member
   end
end

#app/controllers/clients_controller.rb
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :json, only: :data

   def data
      event = client.get_listings_by_event(params[:id])
      respond_with event
   end
end
```

This will allow you to send a request to the aforementioned route, manipulating the response as you require:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'clients/1296393/data',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi there, Please see my edit, I keep getting a 404 error. I'll post all my code in an edit then you can see everything. One second please :)

Comment: Good answer, scope constraints:*

Comment: When you mention a 404 error - can you post that in an update to your question please?

Comment: @RichPeck Heres everything i have done at the moment, Will label it in Edit

Comment: Thanks - looking forward to it!!

Comment: WAIT ignore my edit haha! got a 406 now on the respond with event, I was being stupid before :)

Comment: Interesting - can you post the response in its entirety?

Comment: posted an image of the error, i can post whats in the console

Comment: @RichPeck I've added the console image if it helps :)

Comment: Hey man, I'll come to chat in a second, just doing something if that's okay.

Comment: Hey @RichPeck I won't be able to chat now, Let me know if you need anything else off me !

Comment: @RichPeck I'm at a guess this error is due to the fact its being returned the same as the byebug response. Can i convert this to json?

Comment: @RichPeck Fixed changing it to respond with json